# Seamless jQuery Marquee?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

Is it possible to create a 100% seamless marquee in jQuery (or just javascript but jQuery prefered)?

I've made a simple marquee that moves left until it is off the screen then simply jumps (when out of view) to the right and starts again. However I would love it to not have the wait.

The only way I could think of doing this would be to duplicate the text and put it after the first text, then swap them round again. However I have no idea how to implement this in jQuery, I've been looking at jQuery's `.clone()` but can't get it working correctly, everything jumps.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Let's party like it's 1995!

Comment: Your inclination is exactly right.

Comment: I just created a plugin for that. Hope this helps :) https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery-Marquee

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Given the following markup:

```
<div id="marquee">My Text</div>
```

For the duplication, I'd do something like this:

```
$("#marquee").wrapInner("span"); // wrap "My Text" with a new span
$("#marquee").append($("#marquee span").clone().hide()); // now there are two spans with "My Text"
```

Moving and swapping the spans is pretty easy. Here's a fully functional example:

```
$(function() {

    var marquee = $("#marquee"); 
    marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});

    // wrap "My Text" with a span (old versions of IE don't like divs inline-block)
    marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
    marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center" }); 
    marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone()); // now there are two spans with "My Text"

    // create an inner div twice as wide as the view port for animating the scroll
    marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
    marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");

    // create a function which animates the div
    // $.animate takes a callback for when the animation completes
    var reset = function() {
        $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 3000, 'linear', reset);
    };

    // kick it off
    reset.call(marquee.find("div"));

});
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/uyawi/3/edit).

**Disclaimer:**

I don't recommend this for any professional website. However, it might be useful if you're trying to reproduce a retro 1990's look.

Comment: Still need code to swap once marquee has passed the visible window.

Comment: This is not seamless, there is a huge gap after text end and before text starts again.

Comment: @Evgeny, depends on your definition of seamless. This design makes the screen act like a cylinder, causing the text flowing off one side to immediately appear on the other.

Comment: @Joel, seamless for me means without visible large gaps after text content end and before text content start - given that the gap is not part of the content itself (spaces, tabs, etc).

Comment: @Evgeny, as I said, it depends. From my reading of the question, this is the result the OP was looking for. Your version would not be hard to write I imagine. If you want, create another question and I or someone else will try it.

Comment: @joel still laggy ( maybe becouse of useing css )

Comment: This is a pretty neat script.

Comment: This is awesome @JoelPotter, how might you stop the text from scrolling on `mouseover`?

Comment: Kind of crazy that in 2022 this 12 year old script instantly worked with no bugs, plugged right into my Jquery with no customization needed, and worked better than the 10 libraries I just tried