# The way to stop and continue animation while mouseover and mouseout in JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

E.g:

a simple example to explain:

```
$('.moveDiv').animate({ "margin-left": 2000 }, 20000, 'linear');
```

the `moveDiv element` would move to left when it was loaded,and now, when the `mouse move over` the `moveDiv element`, I wish it to stop and continue to move when the `mouse move out`!

Any ideas?

I found this code in this [question of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143056/seamless-jquery-marquee),so , I just want to modify the code to make it could stop and continue animation when mouse hover!!

[the demo of the code](http://jsbin.com/uyawi/3/edit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pause / Resume Animation Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".moveDiv")
        .mouseover(function () { $(this).pauseAnimation(); })
        .mouseout(function () { $(this).resumeAnimation(); })
        .startAnimation({ "margin-left": 2000 }, 20000, 'linear');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.moveDiv')
    .animate({ "margin-left": 2000 }, 20000, 'linear')
    .hover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true,false);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": 2000 }, 20000, 'linear')
    });
```

let me know how you get on...

oops .stop(true,false);

Comment: It works too.But the animation will get slow down after dozens of hover ！  really verying pitiful

Comment: yeah just played - its because the once the initial animation starts its going to move 2000px over 20 seconds. Pause and then start the animation again at say 1000px - so now the animation has half the distance over the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Just found the plugin suggested in EBCEu4's solution - prob use that but the far-less reuseable solution would be:

```
var duration = 5000;
var target = 200;
$('.moveDiv')
    .animate({ "margin-left": target }, duration, 'linear')
    .hover(
     function(){
        $(this).stop(true,false);
    },
    function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var cur = parseInt($this.css('margin-left'));
        $this.animate({ "margin-left": target }, duration*((target-cur)/target), 'linear')
    });
```