# Pause animation on mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover

I've made a jQuery script that will scroll through a UL list, the problem is that I would like it to pause the animation if the current item in the list is hovered.

I have a timer that calls my ticker function every second, and an update function that updates the list with new items, I havn't included that one as it doesn't have anything to do with the animation.

```
// Initiate a call to ticker every 1second
    var tickerUpdateTimer = setInterval('ticker()', 1000);
```

The ticker functions use the jQuery UI slide function

```
function ticker() {
    if ($('ul#ticker li:first').length == 0)
        tickerUpdate();

        $.when(tickerSlideIn()).then(tickerSlideOut());
}

function tickerSlideIn() {
    $('ul#ticker li:first').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, tickerSpeed).delay(tickerPause);
}

function tickerSlideOut() {
    $('ul#ticker li:first').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, tickerSpeed, function() {$(this).remove();});
}
```

I hope that someone can help me rewrite my functions to pause on hover/mouseover, thanks.

Comment: Already asked and answered mate...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088766/the-way-to-stop-and-continue-animation-while-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-jquery

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find a download location for that plugin. However, shouldn't it be possible to do without the use of that plugin?

Thanks for the heads up tho, been looking at a lot of posts here, but didn't see that one.

Comment: Of course, but the plugin is there so you don't have to rewrite your own version of the animate function.  There is no native pause/continue for jQuery animate - only stop.

Comment: A bit of Googling found this... http://tobia.github.com/Pause/

Comment: Ok, still can't find any download for the plugin tho :/

Comment: There's links on the last page I linked.  See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any plugin:

```
 var tickerUpdateTimer = setInterval('ticker()', 1000), paused = false;

 $('ul#ticker').hover(function(){ paused = true; }, 
                      function(){ paused = false; }); 

 function ticker() {

    if (paused) return;

    if ($('ul#ticker li:first').length == 0)
        tickerUpdate();

        $.when(tickerSlideIn()).then(tickerSlideOut());
 }
```

Comment: `setInterval('ticker()', 1000)` vs `setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 1000)` ? :)

Comment: or even better, `setInterval(ticker, 1000)`

Comment: Oh, thanks - This is a good idea! However, the $.when(tickerSlideIn()).then(tickerSlideOut()); will make the text slide out even if hovered, because the call is already made at that point. Moving the paused check to the slide functions fixes this tho :)