# jquery animation from right to left

Tags: jquery, right-to-left

I am trying to make an animation(Please tell me if my approach is correct) with using css sprites, please check following jquery code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("boat()",20);
});
function boat(){
    $("#boat").animate({right:"+=110%"},20000).css("background-position","0 0").animate({left:"+=110%"},20000).css("background-position","0 -68px")
    setTimeout("boat()",20000);
}
```

**css:**

```
#boat {
    margin-top:160px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:100%;
    width:150px;
    height:68px;
    background-image:url(plane.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Animation works perfect(Right to left and left to right) but there is small issue, css sprite is not working as expected. Its only taking this property `.css("background-position","0 -68px")`

Comment: `left:"+=110%"` looks wrong to me

Comment: @gdoron what should it be then?

Comment: Hiya, Is this any help to you? http://jsfiddle.net/5dqwP/1/ let me know I can set this as answer if this helps! cheers!

Comment: You'll want to include the css inside the `.animate()` api. ie `.animate({ right: "+=110%", background-position: "0 0" });`. I'm not sure if it works with background-position though.

Comment: @seoppc- It looks like it should be `left: "-=100%"`.

Comment: @Tats_innit please post yours answer!

Comment: @seoppc hiya bruv, you mean above comment as answer ? Would love to do that! Do you need any further help? Cheerios

Comment: @Tats_innit yes please check following answer and see my comments

Comment: @seoppc saweet bruv give me few-ish (20) minutes will do that as soon as I am near my laptop. :) have a nice one, cheers

Comment: @seoppc pasted my answer below according to your need, cheerios!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you apply everything in one. 
.css("background-position","0 0") and .css("background-position","0 -68px")
What do you want to achieve? shouldn't it be a callback when the animations is finished?

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    boat();
});
function boat(){
    $("#boat").css("background-position","0px 0px").animate({right:"+=110%"},10000, function() {
        $("#boat").css("background-position","0px -68px").animate({right:"-=110%"},10000, boat);
    });
}
```

you can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/7GV9G/20/

this will be continuous. right to left than left to right than again, loop forever. if you don't want it just once, remove the boat callback from the second animation.

Comment: yes, thats why i want yours help. I am trying to animation it from right to left and left to right

Comment: thanks, can you even tell how can we make this animation smooth?

Comment: its not stopping after successful run (from right to left and left to right) and how can we stop animation on mouseover?

Comment: do you mean the easing of the animation should be linear instead ow swing? like this : ... .animate({right:"+=110%"},10000, 'linear', function() { ...

Comment: do you want to stop, or pause than resume the animation?

Comment: i want to pause then resume on mouseover and stop after 1 successful run(means completing full function, right to left and left to right) please help and thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya as you mentioned above to post my answer :) see this: http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/9/show/
 && code in here : http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/9/ **&&** and my previous start up was this: http://jsfiddle.net/5dqwP/1/

this another version for you exact need http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/20/show/ (wait the blue box goes out of the screen and come back) **or** http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/21/show/  && code in http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/20 here; you can play around and make it pretty. :)

**further edit**

http://jsfiddle.net/8sVDE/ - this might give you more ideas.

** http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation
OR
** [The way to stop and continue animation while mouseover and mouseout in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088766/the-way-to-stop-and-continue-animation-while-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-jquery)

has exact idea what you are looking for.

Hope this helps: (on mouse over the blue box you will get one full repetition)

So, this jsfiddle shows you exactly what you want i.e. **quoting** - "i want to pause then resume on mouseover and stop after 1 successful run(means completing full function, right to left and left to right) "

Please let me know if this helps and have a nice one, cheers!

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    boat();
});
function boat(){
    $("#boat").css("background-position","0px 0px").animate({right:"+=100%"},1000, function() {
        $("#boat").css("background-position","0px -68px").animate({right:"-=100%"},1000).stop();
    });
   // alert('foo');
}



$("#boat").mouseover(function(){
   boat(); 

});
​
```

Comment: thanks for yours answer. how can i pause it on mouseover and play it again on mouseout?

Comment: @seoppc yep man gimme 2 mins! cheers :) But lil clarification - do you mean pause i.e. stop on the location you did mouse over? or stop i.e. return back to original potision of the repetition cycle

Comment: @seoppc also to confirm do you still want only one repition cycle in the start? and latter functionality on mouseover and out? Earlier you wanted it to start again on **mouseover** :) it will be good if you can clarify this - I might be able to help you out, cheers!

Comment: yes stop on the location we did mouseover. and even please suggest if i should use jquery easing for smooth animation?

Comment: @seoppc you can use .slide functionality and on mouse over you can stop it andf on mouse out start back again, I helped someone few days agao I will see if I can dig out the answer. cheers :) **OR** use pauseAnimation plugin wait will give you details!

Comment: @seoppc saweet bruv update the post witjh 2 links check them out cheers also check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/TQz5U/2/

Comment: @seoppc Exactly what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/21/show/ or http://jsfiddle.net/UzLxZ/20/show/ : D'uh obviously you can make it pretty and dont forget to accept and upvote :)) have a nice one, cheers!