# auto-scrolling will pause when user moves mouse over screen / graphs. And auto-scrolling will resume again if mouse movement is stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have working code for autoscrolling for page. I need to do some modification in that. Need to pause autoscrolling when user moves mouse on page  and when there is no mouse movement then autoscrolling will resume.

```
      <script>
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 400000);
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400000); 
        },400000);
        setInterval(function(){
             //  it will take 40 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 400000);
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400000); 
        },400000);

        },8000);
    </script>
```

Comment: please update the html or give us a FIDDLE to get proper help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088766/the-way-to-stop-and-continue-animation-while-mouseover-and-mouseout-in-jquery

Comment: @Sarath  http://jsfiddle.net/QUCWe/1605/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you looking for

```
  var x = 10,
    y = true,
    z = 1,
    maxscroll = 40,
    mixscroll = 10;

setInterval(function() {
    $('html, body').mousemove(function() {
        z = 0;
    });
    if (z === 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            z = x;
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        z = x;
        if (y) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(window).scrollTop() + z) + 'px' }, 300);
            x++;
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(window).scrollTop() + -(z)) + 'px' }, 300);
            x--;
        }
    }

    if (maxscroll < x && y) {
        y = false;
    } else if (x < mixscroll) {
        y = true;
    }
}, 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/donS/9xdz86yu/

Comment: Yes something like this. But your page is not going up again after reaching bottom.  Check this jsfiddle.net/QUCWe/1605

Comment: I didn't spend mush to make it perfect just the concept please check the update hope this help

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.stop()` function in jQuery like ..

```
$("html, body").mouseover(function(){ 
           $(this).stop();
});
```

try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/QUCWe/1606/)**