# Removing gaps in text marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

Does anyone knows if I can make the first item come right after the last item while scrolling and not wait for the last item to disappear before the first item comes out?

I've tried googling for solutions and I understand that I've to use Javascript or JQueries to create the marquee instead of the marquee tag. However, I am completely new to this. Can anyone guide me on how to implement these solutions or provide me with a code that I can use? Thank you so much!

This is the code that I currently have.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
<Title> Hello </Title>

    <style>

#content-wrapper{
  display:table;
}

#content{
  display:table-row;
}

#content>div{
  display:table-cell
}

/*adding some extras for demo purposes*/
#content-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
}
#nav{
  width:25%;
  background:white;
}
#body{
  background:white;
}
</style>

  </head>

<body>

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2" 

    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="nav">
A <br>
B <br>
C <br>
D <br>
E <br>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
1 <br>
2 <br>
3 <br>
4 <br> 
5 <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143056/seamless-jquery-marquee?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! Where do I place the codes in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkh7G/1/ for demo. You might need to change certain code in order to make it work with vertical marquee.

Comment: Alright! I'll go try it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I really have no idea what are the codes to be changed to make it work with vertical marquee. Will it be possible for you to guide me on that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exact you need this the easiest thing to do is Set the scroll delay to a really low number like .01, if you do this then you have to set the scroll speed or the number will get rounded up.

If that is not satisfactory you could kill the default loop of the marquee and make your own. After a certain time, distance, or you could call onFinish() and fire an identical marquee right after. Just like that movie where the magician makes himself disappear and no one can figure out how he does it? what was the name of that one?

A third option is you could reduce the width that the marquee scrolls and offset it to lean towards the side it enters on, it is the sloppiest of the three but try it. Your eyes are too excited to see another marquee that you don't even notice the first one never made it off the page

Comment: Where do I call onFinish()? Do I place it before or after the </marquee> tag? Also, how do I call onFinish() to fire another marquee right after? Thank you so much!

Comment: The comment above is the more elegant than all of my solutions, but the comments suggest otherwise. Here is another link to someone who has solved the problem with excellent reviews. let me know if you need any help getting it to work. Note that it requires a call to jquery

Comment: Alright! I'll go try it out. Thank you so much for your help! How do I make a reference call to jquery?

Comment: Hi, what is the link for the solution? Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/AdvancedStyle/jquery.simplemarquee/blob/master/simplemarquee.html check out that github (github) shows not only the code but the file structure. There are two files in this one. an .html and a .js. take a peak at the html, line 5 is a call to the general jquery (that is not the proper term, i am new too) and line 6 calls jquery specific to a marquee

Comment: there are two ways to call jquery, line 5 references the web address. line 6 is referencing code he downloaded i believe. You can download all of jquery and reference it from your files

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm really at a loss on what to do. Do I just try to add in my codes to the .html codes from github using notepad? Is there anything that I have to change or download?

Comment: ummmmm.....i think you basically need to add your code into theirs as it fits your needs. I am actually no jquery pro I am reading a tutorial right now. I recommend first stepping back from this reading an intro jquery, trying to get just their code to work and then adding yours. If you message me again in about 3-4 hours I should be available to help you out, are you doing this for school or just for fun?

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much! Because I tried to read up but I don't really quite understand as I don't have any backgrounds in HTML or Java. Alright! Do tell me if you're able to help. Thank you! I'm currently having my internship in this company and I'm tasked to create this marquee that shows the name and company of clients.

Comment: oh thats cool, alright Yeah I would be happy to help but I will be working for another 5-6 hours so just comment to send me a reminder before then

Comment: Really appreciate your help! Hmm, I guess it'll be fine since I'm knocking off in another half an hour. Just take your time. I'll comment here again tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do tell me when you're available to help me with the jquery alright? Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh yeah I didnt forget I am having trouble with one thing, isnt a big problem and I will let you know. I am hoping within an hour or two

Comment: I don't what I am doing but I can not get this to work. I have been going at it for quite some time. I am going to keep trying but if you are on a deadline for this I recommend seeking alternative solutions. After failing many ways I had the idea to save each element in an array. Then loop through the array, creating a new marquee for each letter that followed each other. Something you might be able to work from, i will keep you posted

Comment: Oh. Alright sure! Do keep me posted! Thank you! I have to complete it by tomorrow.

Comment: Each element would mean each line of text that comes out? I have close to 200 of elements omg.

Comment: You would put them in an array [1, 2, 3, 4] and then you would only have to do something like " foreach value in arrayname[] do this code"  the code i just typed there is not correct but just to give you a better idea. It iterates through the array for you

Comment: Oh I see. Will it be possible for me to continue putting the elements in a table like what I currently have?

Comment: O ya, If you use the approach you are then going to have to put that code in an infinite loop. which is very simple, I am getting dragged away from the computer right now, send me questions i will try to get back asap

Comment: Oh, so I will just have to put the code in an infinite loop? Hmm, how do I do it? Alright sure! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmm, if the html marquee is coded to be infinite, there will still be a gap as the first line will only appear again after the last line disappears.

Comment: Hi, have you figured out how to do the codings yet?

Comment: no, copying the code from this link http://javascript.about.com/library/blctmarquee1.htm is the closest I came.

Comment: Hmm. Do I have to edit any of the codes for the marquee.js or to my existing code? Because the code provided in the link doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/hujFj/ does that link work, i just signed up for jsfiddle so i could show this to you. It is by no means pretty cause I just copied and pasted code

Comment: click run at the top to see it move

Comment: Oh. I managed to get the codes working. But how do I change it to a vertical marquee? And will it be possible for me to continue putting the values in a table if I use this code? Thank you!

Comment: .marquee {position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:500px;
     height:22px;
     border:solid black 1px;
     } add direction:up to that part, and for the table part, try it you might need to convert it to a string

Comment: .marquee {position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
     border:solid white 1px;
     direction:up;
     } Is this correct? The marquee is still scrolling from right to left though. How do I convert the table to a string?

Comment: Hmm. As for the table part, I was given a new set of instructions to use data from microsoft excel.

Comment: I've published the excel file as a webpage. Will it be possible to convert it as a vertical marquee?

Comment: changing the direction attribute to up if you have a horizontal marquee