# Marquee-like vertical scrolling text (+stopping)

Tags: html, css, text, scroll, marquee

I would like to have a text, that scrolls vertically and everytime a line of text is 100% visible it stops for a certain time, then it rolls on to the next line of text, and so on. It should be appliable to any amount of text lines.

Do you guys maybe can give me some keywords or a solution for this? After 1 hour google search I couldnt find any solution on my own, I guess I'm just missing some matching words for that (and CSS/js knowledge of course ;)).

King Regards,
JensDoe

Comment: One thing to let you know, since you are new. SO is for Questions that you need help with, not for us to write your code for you. Give me a moment and i will try to answer your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't expected anyone to write the code for me tho, hehe. Just a little hint where I have to head to find out by myself would be enough :) Any help is highly appreciated which can help me and sorry again for the stupid question. I shoul've had included my code so far, just thought it would be useless. And big thanks for your answer & efforts :)

Comment: That is fine. I just wanted to let you know before you got a lot of down votes. Sorry if it sounded bad lol. I tried to give you a few examples below. @JensDoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by using the  tag in HTML> Here is some ways to do it in JQuery. http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ and here http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html.

Here is an already created question: [Seamless jQuery Marquee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143056/seamless-jquery-marquee)

If there is any more info you need, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot Elite Gamer! So jQuery is the way to go I guess! I will read into it and try to get it work with that. I will come back here and post results. Thank you!

Comment: Okay´, the first link is exactly what I was looking for. Problem solved! Thanks again Elite Gamer!!!!

Comment: Ok, your welcome, please accept my answer if you found it useful. Glad to help! @JensDoe Just click the Checkmark by the answer. Thanks